# Difference between python2 and python3 in the decode function

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Recently, I watched a video about writing a code to decode the title and contents of the file from decimal numbers into strings. However, it is written in python2 so I decided to rewrite the code in python3. Unfortunately, I am having trouble in decoding the contents of the picture.

### This is the original code in python2:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

directory = '1262404985085867488371'

def decrypt(number): 
    return hex(int(number))[2:].replace("L","").decode("hex")


os.chdir(directory)
for i in os.listdir('.'):
    try:
        print(decrypt(i))
        c = open(i).read()
        open(decrypt(i),'w').write(decrypt(c))
        #o.write(decrypt(c))

    except:
        print("FAILED WITH",i)
```

### And this is the code written in python3:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os

directory = '1262404985085867488371'

def decrypt(number): 
    hex_num = hex(int(number))[2:].replace("L","")
    return  bytes.fromhex(hex_num).decode("ascii")


os.chdir(directory)
for i in os.listdir('.'):
    try:
        print(decrypt(i))
        c = open(i).read()
        open(decrypt(i),'w').write(decrypt(c))
        #o.write(decrypt(c))

    except:
        print("FAILED WITH",i)
```

Can anyone help me to have a look how can I solve this problem? This is the problem about:

> My computer got infected with ransomware and now none of my documents are accessible anymore! If you help me out, I'll reward you a flag!
>   https://static.tjctf.org/7459b0c272ba30c9fea94391c7d7051d78e1732c871c3a6f27070fcb34f9e734_encrypted.tar.gz

Basically, I have tried by changing the ascii into utf-8 and open the file with the mode in "wb" or "rb" but neither of them works...

Comment: do you get any errors? if so, please include them.

Comment: If you can include any other information so we can reproduce the problem would be helpful, for example [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: the edit to your code capitalizing `directory` variable does *not* improve code formatting. python syntax encourages lower-case variables.

Comment: @davedwards Alright. Thanks. This is my first time using stack overflow so I am not too familiar on the syntax yet. Btw, I have reedited to provide the source of my problem.

Comment: no worries, thanks. but that link is protected by username and password, so we cannot see what you see, the picture, or the problem description or contents.

Comment: Alright. Let me try to post the questions and the link over here!!

Comment: ok, just be sure not to post any private or secure information. thanks.

Comment: Ok. This is just a computer security challenge competition held by a high school that is opened to public through online.

Comment: I don't know much about the problem you are facing, but when I extracted that `tar.gz` file you linked to, there is a file `HAHAHA.txt` which includes `"All your files have been encrypted with a uncrackable algorithm.
You are now screwed forever."`. Do you really think this is a safe challenge? I would be very careful. especially since your question includes `"My computer got infected with ransomware "`

Comment: Yeaa definitely. Basically the title of the files and the contents of the files have been encrypted into decimal numbers. And my code is aimed to decode it to strings.

Comment: Ok cool, just making sure.

Comment: There is 1 video writeup for the challenge. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m9FuGso8BE8

Comment: Hm, interesting. It doesn't produce any errors for me, so far I only get empty files. It seems like it's related to [Decode Hex String in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283984/decode-hex-string-in-python-3), or [Convert(decode) hex string to ASCII or any other understandable format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29547104/convertdecode-hex-string-to-ascii-or-any-other-understandable-format), but I can't solve it yet, will keep trying and update with any success.

Comment: Yeaa, it does not produce any error for me also. Basically, I got empty files when I compiled using the python3 code but I got the image files when I compiled using the python2 code. I am thinking maybe the problem is on the writing the byte object or whatever into a file because the decrypt function actually works fine with the name of the file. It only fails during writing the conversion into the contents of the file.I have tried to debug my code and I found out the problem is on this line when the decrypt function is called with the c as the argument.
open(decrypt(i),'w').write(decrypt(c))

Comment: Maybe it is because of the newline or what from the read() function and I tried to replace newline with empty string but it still doesnt work loll...

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to jump the gun here and since you did not include any examples and\or errors I will guess you got this kind of error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd7 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This is caused by a file\directory with a unicode name, which in turn triggers this exception when you try to decode with ascii as in `decode("ascii")`.

Instead, try decoding with "utf-8".

Comment: Actually I have tried with that before but it still doesn't work. I am thinking maybe it has something to do with the byte object.

Comment: That's great so if you tried something already, include it in the question so we can focus our help instead of taking wild guesses :P