# Hex to String convertion

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string like this :

```
message='भी मिलता था। सरोपा #variable# भेंट करना अब शायद सिर्फ सिख परंपरा में ही बचा समाज की #variable# गहराई नापते रहे हैं गुणाधर'
```

I have converted this string to hex using

```
output = ''.join(hex(ord(c)) for c in message) 

output1 = output.replace('0x','0')
```

and the **final hex** is :

```
'092d0940020092e093f09320924093e0200925093e096402009380930094b092a093e02002307606107206906106206c065023020092d09470902091f020091509300928093e0200905092c0200936093e092f09260200938093f0930094d092b0200938093f0916020092a09300902092a0930093e020092e0947090202009390940020092c091a093e0200938092e093e091c0200915094002002307606107206906106206c065023020091709390930093e09080200928093e092a09240947020093009390947020093909480902020091709410923093e09270930'
```

How can I get back my original string from encoded hex?

OR How can I get back my original string from output(without replacing)?

Comment: Does `output1` contain the `x`s yet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert from ASCII string encoded in Hex to plain ASCII?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9641440/convert-from-ascii-string-encoded-in-hex-to-plain-ascii)

Comment: @MichaelButscher i have edited output ...check now

Comment: binascii.a2b_hex()?

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar i have already tried that one but its not working

Comment: @Mntfr i have tried that but i'm getting output ( hex ) in different way .... i want my original string back without any change in  hex code

Comment: How can you distinguish between a `'0'` that was originally a `'0'` and one that is a replacement for `'0x'`? - you lost some information there.  Will you always know the original character set/encoding?

Comment: why cant you use hexlify?

Comment: @VaniPolnedi I just saw your edit, which is way simpler when you can keep the `0x` ! :)

Answer (score 2):

The binascii library already has functions for coding and encoding in hex

```
import binascii

message='भी मिलता था। सरोपा #variable# भेंट करना अब शायद सिर्फ सिख परंपरा में ही बचा समाज की #variable# गहराई नापते रहे हैं गुणाधर'
messageEncoded = binascii.hexlify(message.encode())
print(messageEncoded)

messageDecoded =  binascii.unhexlify(messageEncoded)
print(messageDecoded.decode())
```

Comment: i want hex code like above only  ( '092d0940020092e093f09320924093e0200925093e096402009380930094b092a093e02002307606107206906106206c065023020092d09470902091f020091509300928093e0200905092c0200936093e092f09260200938093f0930094d092b0200938093f0916020092a09300902092a0930093e020092e0947090202009390940020092c091a093e0200938092e093e091c0200915094002002307606107206906106206c065023020091709390930093e09080200928093e092a09240947020093009390947020093909480902020091709410923093e09270930' )

Comment: for case 2: without replacing how can i get back my original string?

Answer (score 1):

As some commentaries already specified, it is impossible to decode if you replace `0x` by `0`, the closest I could get is the following

```
# Deencoding
hexs = []
tmp = ''
for i in range(len(output1)):
    if i < len(output1) - 1 and output1[i] == '0' and output1[i+1] != '0':
        hexs.append(tmp)
        tmp = ''
    else:
        tmp += output1[i]
if tmp != '':
    hexs.append(tmp)

print(''.join(chr(int(c,16)) for c in hexs[1:]))
```

Which will fail because in your hex code you have `902`, how do you determine if it is 2 characters `9` and `2` or only one `902`?

If you can keep the `0x`, you can simply use the other commands to get it back with `int` and `chr` as follow

```
print(''.join(chr(int(c, 16)) for c in output[2:].split('0x')))
```

But the best way to do  what you want is probably to use `binascii`

Comment: Thank you, It worked well for output. Let me check for output1 also.

Comment: @VaniPolnedi It does not work :( some of the characters are wrong, because there is no way to differentiate `209` from `2` and `9` unfortunately, it is close enough but not the same ^^

Comment: Can i get back my output from output1?

Comment: in my code i have 902 which determines only one 902 not 2 characters

Comment: I agree. But you cannot determine a logic which is not hardcoded to split on some zeros but not all (which means How can you tell a computer "20902" is "2 902" and not "209 2"?

Comment: @VaniPolnedi So basically, it is impossible to get back your hex from output1 without hardcoding the solution a bit

Comment: @VaniPolnedi Have you got any question or do you have any insights on how the split can be performed?

Comment: solved this case in another way ( changed hex encoding but output is same )