# 'No such file or directory' ERROR information when using "PRINT"

Tags: python, printing

When I 'print' some hex string, some interesting error information in python, I wonder why this error is caused.

Win10(I tried it on ubuntu, No ERROR),python 2.7

```py
enc_hex = '''f982f01c'''
enc_ascii = enc_hex.decode('hex')
print(enc_ascii)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\xxxx.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(enc_ascii)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Well,in fact I want to know why "print" a special set of hex will cause file operation, other hex string will not error

Comment: there is no parenthesis for print in python 2.7
`print enc_ascii`
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: @WSMathias9 You still can use it with parens

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert from ASCII string encoded in Hex to plain ASCII?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9641440/convert-from-ascii-string-encoded-in-hex-to-plain-ascii)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `codecs.decode`:

```
import codecs
enc_hex = '''f982f01c'''
enc_ascii = codecs.decode(enc_hex, 'hex')
print(enc_ascii)
```

Output:

```
b'\xf9\x82\xf0\x1c'
```

Comment: Thanks, The codec can solve this problem. And I want to know the reason of this error, I think print shouldn't to call the file operation

Comment: @phantom0301 Because string actually doesn't have a function called `.decode`, Btw, please accept if it works.

Comment: @phantom0301 Anyways, if it works, it's worth an accept

Answer (score 0):

it seems like directory problems . in windows you have to use forward slash (/) while accessing the directory.similar was happened in my case then i use forward slash in windows then it works.