# Decode a hex file that into plaintext English

Tags: python, file, hex, plaintext

I want to read a file that has hex. For example the file contains this `"\x70\x79\x74\x68\x6f\x6e\x70\x79\x74\x68\x6f\x6e\x70\x79\x74\x68\x6f\x6e"`.

I tried to read the file and print it but when I print it I see the same hex code and not the plaintext English. But when I manually copy the hex code into the `print()` function of Python, it shows the plaintext English.
However, the `print()` function in the below function only shows the hex code and not English.

```
with open('sample_hex_file_2.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
    print(data)
```

I want to read the file that contains the hex code and convert it into English and print it on screen.

Comment: If I do this in perl, I get "pythonpythonpython": `print "\x70\x79\x74\x68\x6f\x6e\x70\x79\x74\x68\x6f\x6e\x70\x79\x74\x68\x6f\x6e"`. SHouldn't be that hard in any other language. Of course you could do that yourself, too. So what's the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert from ASCII string encoded in Hex to plain ASCII?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9641440/convert-from-ascii-string-encoded-in-hex-to-plain-ascii)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please tell me you can remove the quotes on the input file? Once we are through that hurdle, you can use this.

```
def main():
    with open('sample_hex_file_2.txt', 'r') as f:
        data = f.read()
        text=""
        for item in data.split('\\x'):
            text += (bytearray.fromhex(item).decode())
        print(text)
if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

Leads to `pythonpythonpython`