# How to convert list of Hex values into Ascii string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, hex, ascii

I have a list of Hex value variables in my python code.

I need to convert into ASCII string.

Can someone please suggest to me, how to convert it?

HexList = ['0x0', '0x30', '0x32', '0x31', '0x30', '0x42', '0x32', '0x33', '0x38', '0x30', '0x30', '0x30', '0x31', '0x30', '0x32','0x43','0x30']

Expected value of Ascii string after the conversion= `0210B238000102C0`

Comment: The output can be reproduced by doing something like `''.join(chr(int(c, 16)) for c in HexList[1:])`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert from ASCII string encoded in Hex to plain ASCII?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9641440/convert-from-ascii-string-encoded-in-hex-to-plain-ascii)

Comment: why did you start the index from 1 instead of 0 in HexList?

Comment: 0x0 doesn't do anything.

Comment: Specific duplicate answer:

`bytearray.fromhex("70 61 75 6C").decode()` where 70 61 75 6C can be replaced